# Get tableview data to reset before the user begins scrolling

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am encountering a weird problem that I have come to understand is actually normal?
I did some reading on UITableViews and I noticed that the reason why my table is not updating its height automatically is because the data rests when the user scrolls.
I am updating the height of my font throughout my app. This works fine with my ListViews but I noticed some of the data in my cells from my tableview were cut off and it would resize the cell when the user would scroll down and then back up.
Unfortunately the cell that is being cut off is the first one on the list, so it's pretty obvious. I am working with both iOS and Android but Android does not do this, so I assume it's an issue with UITableView. Is there a way of getting the tableview to reset automatically?
I've read a few answers that deal with Swift and Constraints and I did not apply constraints to my CellViews and I don't think I can.

My Table looks like this:

```
<TableView x:Name="SettingsTable"
     HasUnevenRows="True">
  <TableRoot>  
    <TableSection Title="User Preferences">
       <ViewCell Tapped="FontResizePage">
           <StackLayout>
              <Image Source="gears.png"/>
              <Label Text="Font Resize" FontSize="{Binding Pt17}"/>       
           </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell>
    </TableSection>
    <TableSection Title="Security & Login">
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout> 
             <Image Source="lock.png"/>
             <Label Text="Password" FontSize="{Binding Pt17}"/>                                                            </StackLayout></ViewCell>
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Hi, do you add `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `ViewModel`? Then modify the data of Model, the TableView will update.

Comment: I did not think of doing that. Would I need to make the table a dynamic one? I think it's currently considered static. Like all the data is not loaded from a DataSource.

Comment: Okey, I want to make sure that whether it's a xamarin forms project?

Comment: Hey @JuniorJiang-MSFT I figured this out. I ended up doing what you said and I also changed this table to a grouped Listview. Seemed a lot easier than dealing with a tableview.

Comment: Okey, gald you have solved that. Ypu could update your solution as an asnwer, then it will be helpful for others who have the same problems.